# Display Measure depending on Date, combine two measure from different dates

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

Background: 
I am preparng a dataset for a report. 
To simplify lets say it is two measures, one Category and a time dimension. 
The main Report Parameter is todays date. 
I would like to see the first Measure from yesterday (Value 000) and the second measures
from the day before yesterday (Value 001). Because previous days data is not available yet for Value 001.

Lets assume 2020-04-27 is today (passed on from the Reporting Tool SSRS).

### AS-IS

```
SELECT {[Measures].[Value 000], [Measures].[Value 001]} ON COLUMNS
    , ( {[DIM Category].[Category].&[1], [DIM Category].[Category].&[2]}, 
    [DIM Date].[Y-M-D ISO].[Date].[2020-04-27].LAG(2): [DIM Date].[Y-M-D ISO].[Date].[2020-04-27].LAG(1)
    )
 ON ROWS
FROM [My_Cube]
```

**Output:**

```
                        [Value 000]     [Value 001]     
Category 1  2020-04-25      88              16
Category 1  2020-04-26      89              (null)
Category 2  2020-04-25      90              14
Category 2  2020-04-26      92              (null)
```

I tried two MDX-Queries for each date and combined the Sets in the Reporting tool but I am wondering if there is a comfortable way to do that in one MDX query.
The following would be the desired output.

### To-Be

**Output:**

```
                [Value 000]     [Value 001]                 
Category 1          89              16          (Value from day before, for Value 0001) 
Category 2          92              14
```

The Date doesn't need to be shown in the output (but can be)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve the issue by using calculated measures. Follwoing example is based on adventureworks . I want to rebuild your senario for Jan 23 2013

The initial query is there to show values for yesterday abd day before
    with 
    member measures.Yesterday 
    as 
    sum([Date].[Date].currentmember.lag(1),[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])

```
member measures.DayBefore 
as 
sum([Date].[Date].currentmember.lag(2),[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
select 
{
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],measures.Yesterday ,measures.DayBefore
}
on columns,

{
([Product].[Category].[Category],[Date].[Date].&[20130120]:[Date].[Date].&[20130123])
}
on rows 
from 
[Adventure Works]
where [Date].[Date].&[20130123]
```

Result

[image]

Now lets remove the date from the rows and put it in where

```
with 
member measures.Yesterday 
as 
sum([Date].[Date].currentmember.lag(1),[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])

member measures.DayBefore 
as 
sum([Date].[Date].currentmember.lag(2),[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
select 
{
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],measures.Yesterday ,measures.DayBefore
}
on columns,

{
([Product].[Category].[Category])
}
on rows 
from 
[Adventure Works]
where [Date].[Date].&[20130123]
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot. I applied the same logic. For t my query given it looks like this:    ```WITH MEMBER [Measures].DayBefore
AS
SUM([DIM Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER.LAG(1), [Measures].[Value 001]) --DayBefore Yesterday

SELECT { [Measures].[Value 000], 
  [Measures].DayBefore
 } ON COLUMNS
 , {[DIM Category].[Category].&[1], [DIM Category].[Category].&[2]}
 ON ROWS
FROM [BI_Base]
WHERE [DIM Date].[Y-M-D ISO].[Date].[2020-04-27] --Yesterday```